# How to Link To Just Above A Header Within the HTML Page

Tags: html, css

I have created a one page website where each link in the nav bar scrolls to a different section of that page. The issue is that my nav bar is sticky and when I link the list items to my specific headers, the page scrolls so that the nav bar ends up covering the section header.

Is there a way that I can link my nav bar items to an area just above the headers so that when it scrolls it is not covered by the nav bar. I was thinking possibly having it scroll to a specific y value? Not sure how that would work.

Comment: You can, using javascript for example (using `scrollTop` and the like), but generally speaking you're likely better off asking yourself, should there really be content under the nav bar? shouldn't your content canvas's topside match the bottom of your navbar ?

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the layout using css. If this were your code:

```
<a href="#goto">Jump</a>
<!-- yadda yadda yadda -->
<h2 id="goto">Header</h2>
```

You can adjust the h2 id with the following (using margin-top and height):

```
h2::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -285px; 
  height: 285px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

More detailed info can be found at: https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. What does the ::before do in CSS? I have been wondering that for a while now and still haven't gotten an answer.

Comment: It's a pseudo selector and it inserts content before the selected element. Likewise, you can insert content after an element with  ::after.

Comment: So how does it not interfere with the content above it?

Comment: I'm not 100% positively sure, but I believe it's because the content for ::before becomes the first child of the selected element. Therefore it is acting on that element's box.